# Laravel, pimpable. filter request by null

Tags: php, laravel

In my DB table I have column 'deleted_at'. If I delete the model, the value of 'deleted_at' is the date & time of deleting. In other case the value is NULL.

Now I want get all rows, those have 'deleted_at=NULL' (existing models).

This query works perfect, it returns all deleted models (where deleted_at is not null)

```
$result = SearchContract::pimp(['deleted_at' => '!null'])->paginate($limit)->toArray();
```

So I need the rows where 'deleted_at = NULL'.

We use the Pimpable library, here is the link [[https://github.com/jedrzej/pimpable]](https://github.com/jedrzej/pimpable)

Comment: Have you tried SearchContract::pimp(['deleted_at' => 'null'])->paginate($limit)->toArray();

Comment: this  doesn't work. From Docs >> In SQL, the NULL value is never true in comparison to any other value, even NULL. An expression that contains NULL always produces a NULL value unless otherwise indicated in the documentation for the operators and functions involved in the expression.

Comment: Did you tired SearchContract::pimp(['deleted_at' => NULL])->paginate($limit)->toArray();  ?

Comment: try this 

`$result = SearchContract::whereNull('deleted_at')->paginate($limit)->toArray();`

documentation is [her](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: The solution is.                                                                                                       $result = SearchContract::pimp()->whereNull('deleted_at')->paginate($limit)->toArray(); In this case filtring and pagination work perfectly. thank you all